# What is 'would stop its deployment' here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In a [blog](http://www.nytimes.com/aponline/2016/02/16/world/asia/ap-as-koreas-sanctions.html) of the NYT, I can't understand the last part of this paragraph:

> On Monday, the Chinese government-run English-language China Daily called THAAD a serious regional security threat, and said that "a sanctions package that is sufficient for Pyongyang to reevaluate its nuclear program," ***would stop its deployment.***

Is it a continuation of the sentence written in an inverted comma? What is the exact meaning of the last phrase in this context?

Comment: This might well be a typo. Do you understand the sentence if the comma is removed and the quotation marks are moved to the end  (after 'deployment')? "Its" refers to  the sanctions package.

Comment: Agreed; this sentence does not need that last comma. It's possible whoever wrote/edited it included that comma solely because the quote was ending.

Rephrased: *The newspaper said that the deployment of THAAD would be stopped by a sanctions package sufficient to halt North Korea's nuclear program.*

Answer (score 1):

The sentence in the quotes (not inverted commas as you've stated) is most likely a quote, and the bolded part of the sentence in this context would be referring to the deployment of the nuclear program referred to in the quote.